# Eclipse installer stops installing on windows

Tags: eclipse, windows

I just downloaded the new eclipse installer for windows but it keeps 'hanging' on 'installing' for several minutes now and won't proceed,

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just run the installer with administration rights

-> go to the install file;

-> right-click the donwloaded file

-> choose 'run as administrator'...

(go throug the installation)

...It works flawlessly :)